# Tag Date to correct Data range

Tags: excel-formula

I have data in 2 sheets.I sheet has salary details of employee and effective date and other sheet has date from which employee was tagged to particular grade.

Now I have to get what was the grade of the employee in the salary sheet.I need to check start date of CTC sheet with Range if dates in which it falls in Grade sheet and get the grade in that row

[CTC file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOpZm.png)

[Grade details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC5VC.png)

Comment: What were your attempts so far? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what version Excel you have, here are two quick methods to achieve what has been described (screenshot and [this](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j962KKuAYFvrxIJfLE?e=S6fqCH) workbook refer):

**Office 365**

```
=FILTER($M$3:$M$5,1*($J$3:$J$5=B3)*(D3<=$L$3:$L$5)*(D3>=$K$3:$K$5))
```

**No Office 365 compatible version**

```
=INDEX(INDEX($M$3:$M$5,MATCH(1*(D3<=$L$3:$L$5)*(D3>=$K$3:$K$5)*(B3=$J$3:$J$5),($D$3:$D$13<=$L$3:$L$5)*($D$3:$D$13>=$K$3:$K$5)*($B$3:$B$13=$J$3:$J$5),0)),1)
```

**Notes**

- Only checks Start in CTC ('salary') file falls within range of
  Start/End in Grade file (does not check anything re: 'End' in CTC)
- 2nd equation returns 1st match should multiple exist (1st will return #Spill! should this occur)

[image: Office 365 vs No Office 365 compatible version of Excel]